# React Native: How should I incorporate this code snippet into my existing AndroidManifest.xml?

Tags: react-native, android-manifest

In my React Native app, I need to add the following code to my AndroidManifest.xml file:

```
<manifest ...>
    <queries>
        <intent>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <data android:scheme="https"/>
        </intent>
    </queries>
</manifest>
```

My AndroidManifest.xml file currently looks like this:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  package="com.intowconnect">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_STATE" />

    <application
      android:name=".MainApplication"
      android:label="@string/app_name"
      android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
      android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
      android:allowBackup="false"
      android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
      <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize|uiMode"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"
        android:launchMode="singleTop"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
      </activity>
      <activity android:name="com.facebook.react.devsupport.DevSettingsActivity" />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

I'm not sure how to incorporate the code snippet into this. Is there a place I can just insert the `<queries>` block? Or do I need to change the format of my existing file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pre Requirement for Android Studio

**Android Studio version minimum 4.1.3 with Gradle Plugin 6.8.2**

For use queries you should write queries code in out of application tag not inside application tag

```
<manifest ...>
<application .... />
<queries>
    <intent>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
        <data android:scheme="https"/>
    </intent>
</queries>
</manifest>
```

Comment: That did it, thanks!